# How to get the data in each row using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get all the values in a row ..ie get each cell in the row ,when the user selects a row that has the `class="trSelected"`.

I had something like this but wasnt sure how to get the value(s) for the rows that has the class "trSelected"

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(app.rootElement).find('table tr').click(function(event){
    jQuery('.trSelected', this).each( function(){
        var  rowval = $(this).attr('') + $(this).attr('') ..
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
         <tr class="erow trSelected" style="background-color: yellow;">
       <td align="left" abbr="SEV">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 40px;"><a class="severity1-img" href="#" title="Critical" alt="Critical">Critical</a></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Verify">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 140px;"><span title="No">No</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Ins">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;"><span title="lwqun050">lwqun050</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
          <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;"><span title="1">1</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
          <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;"><span title="undefined">undefined</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;"><span title="Host">Host</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Owner">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;"><span title="SYSTEM">SYSTEM</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Name">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;"><span title="Down">undefined</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="LastNotifiedAt">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 130px;"><span title="2012-07-23T13:57:11.000-04:00">2012-07-23T13:57:11.000-04:00</span></div>
       </td>
    </tr>

<tr class="erow trSelected" style="background-color: yellow;">
       <td align="left" abbr="SEV">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 40px;"><a class="severity1-img" href="#" title="Critical" alt="Critical">Critical</a></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Verify">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 140px;"><span title="No">No</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Ins">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;"><span title="lwqun050">lwqun050</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
          <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;"><span title="1">1</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
          <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;"><span title="undefined">undefined</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;"><span title="Host">Host</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Owner">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;"><span title="SYSTEM">SYSTEM</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Name">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;"><span title="Down">undefined</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="LastNotifiedAt">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 130px;"><span title="2012-07-23T13:57:11.000-04:00">2012-07-23T13:57:11.000-04:00</span></div>
       </td>
    </tr>

<tr class="erow " style="background-color: yellow;">
       <td align="left" abbr="SEV">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 40px;"><a class="severity1-img" href="#" title="Critical" alt="Critical">Critical</a></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Verify">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 140px;"><span title="No">No</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Ins">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;"><span title="lwqun050">lwqun050</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
          <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;"><span title="1">1</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
          <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;"><span title="undefined">undefined</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;"><span title="Host">Host</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Owner">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;"><span title="SYSTEM">SYSTEM</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="Name">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;"><span title="Down">undefined</span></div>
       </td>
       <td align="left" abbr="LastNotifiedAt">
          <div style="text-align: left; width: 130px;"><span title="2012-07-23T13:57:11.000-04:00">2012-07-23T13:57:11.000-04:00</span></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please, provide a complete example and show what you already did.

Comment: I think you want `$(this).text()`

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up doing to return the values of the row selected and this worked.

It captures the event based on trSelected and returns the item and their associated values  in the row or row(s)

Thanks eveyone

```
jQuery(app.rootElement).find('.flexme1 ').click(function(event){
  console.log(this);
  console.log('Hello Inside  event');
  console.log(event);
      jQuery(this).find('.trSelected').each( function(){
        console.log(this);
          console.log(
              '  Sev: '   + jQuery('td[abbr="Sev"] >div', this).text() +
              '  Ins '   + jQuery('td[abbr="Ins"] >div', this).text() +
              '  Impact: ' + jQuery('td[abbr="Impact"] >div span', this).text()
          );
      });
  });
```